# Solving intersection between fourth order polynomial and quadratic

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can't think of how to solve intersections between these two equations, probably just missing something. But how would I actually go about solving this?

Equations:

a) $1.65*x^4-0.4$

b) $-(x+0.5)^2+1$

So far I have:
$1.65*x^4-0.4=-x^2-1x+0.75$

$1.65*x^4+x^2+x-0.75-0.4=0$

$1.65*x^4+x^2+x-1.15=0$

Comment: I suspect that in the context of the course you're taking, you are expected to solve _graphically_ (which will give approximate solutions). If so, just graph the two functions
$$y=1.65x^4-0.4\\y=-(x+0.5)^2+1$$
using a graphing calculator, and then trace the graph to get the approximate values of the $x$-coordinates of the points where the graphs intersect.

Comment: @quasi That's a big help thanks, although the course currently asks for the question to be solved mathematically

Comment: Is it from a book? If so, which one?

Comment: @quasi Its a PSMT so no book, let me clarify with my teacher and I'll get back to you

Comment: Yes, you should check. By the way, PSMT means what?

Comment: @quasi Problem Solving Maths Task

Comment: Did you check with your teacher with regard to the assigned problem?

Comment: Multiply the quartic by 100 and divide by 5.  A simpler graph?

Comment: @quasi Yes, can be solved graphically, so I'll go down that route, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Working wtih whole numbers, the equation to be solved is
$$33 x^4+20 x^2+20 x-23=0$$ If you are patient and use $\Delta$ (the discriminant of [the quartic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function)), you should find that, since $\Delta <0$, there is only two real roots.

So, now, consider that you look for the two zero's of function
$$f(x)=33 x^4+20 x^2+20 x-23$$ and use inspection : $f(-1)=10$, $f(0)=-23$, $f(1)=50$. So, even without graphing, we know where, more or less, are the roots : $-1 < x_1 <0$ and $0<x_2<1$.

Since the second derivative is positive $(f''(x)=396 x^2+40)$, in order to avoid any overshoot of the solution (by Darboux theorem), let us at the known points where the function is positive. Now, apply Newton method.

The iterates woill be given by
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{99 x_n^4+20 x_n^2+23}{132 x_n^3+40 x_n+20}$$

For the negative root, you will have
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & -1.00000 \\
 1 & -0.934211 \\
 2 & -0.926957 \\
 3 & -0.926875
\end{array}
\right)$$
and for the positive root
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.000000 \\
 1 & 0.739583 \\
 2 & 0.617188 \\
 3 & 0.594070 \\
 4 & 0.593370
\end{array}
\right)$$

All of the above could easily be done using Excel or even a pocket calculator.

Answer (score 0):

According to Mathematica, the exact form of the two real solutions to your quartic equation are given by
$$x= -\frac{1}{3 \sqrt{\frac{22}{-20-\frac{2177}{\sqrt[3]{91585+9
   \sqrt{230930018}}}+\sqrt[3]{91585+9 \sqrt{230930018}}}}}-\frac{1}{2}
   \sqrt{-\frac{80}{99}+\frac{4354}{99 \sqrt[3]{91585+9 \sqrt{230930018}}}-\frac{2}{99}
   \sqrt[3]{91585+9 \sqrt{230930018}}+20 \sqrt{\frac{2}{11
   \left(-20-\frac{2177}{\sqrt[3]{91585+9 \sqrt{230930018}}}+\sqrt[3]{91585+9
   \sqrt{230930018}}\right)}}}\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{1}{2}
   \sqrt{-\frac{80}{99}+\frac{4354}{99 \sqrt[3]{91585+9 \sqrt{230930018}}}-\frac{2}{99}
   \sqrt[3]{91585+9 \sqrt{230930018}}+20 \sqrt{\frac{2}{11
   \left(-20-\frac{2177}{\sqrt[3]{91585+9 \sqrt{230930018}}}+\sqrt[3]{91585+9
   \sqrt{230930018}}\right)}}}-\frac{1}{3 \sqrt{\frac{22}{-20-\frac{2177}{\sqrt[3]{91585+9
   \sqrt{230930018}}}+\sqrt[3]{91585+9 \sqrt{230930018}}}}}.$$

Obviously, your teacher isn't expecting you to find this (Matheamtica probably got this by plugging the coefficients into the quartic equation or something of the sort, which you are not expected to be able to do by hand). You are probably expected to give the approximate numerical answers by plotting the graph, which are
$$x\approx -0.92687,0.59337.$$